# Exception in DataSet Visualizer for datasets with multiple tables - vs 2008 pro

Tags: visual-studio-2008

In Visual Studio 2008 pro (Version 9.0.30729.1 SP) I always get an error when trying to use dataset visualizer on datasets with multiple tables. The first table is fine, when I select any other table I get the message below. It's easy to get around by adding a watch on each table, but still annoying. Anyone else have trouble with this?

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at EnhancedDataSetVisualizer.VisualizerCommunicator.GetTableCellValue(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 colIndex)
   at EnhancedDataSetVisualizer.DataSetForm.dataGridView_CellValueNeeded(Object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellValueNeeded(DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellValueNeeded(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.GetValue(Int32 rowIndex)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.PaintWork(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.PaintCells(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle rowBounds, Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates rowState, Boolean isFirstDisplayedRow, Boolean isLastVisibleRow, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle rowBounds, Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates rowState, Boolean isFirstDisplayedRow, Boolean isLastVisibleRow)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PaintRows(Graphics g, Rectangle boundingRect, Rectangle clipRect, Boolean singleHorizontalBorderAdded)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PaintGrid(Graphics g, Rectangle gridBounds, Rectangle clipRect, Boolean singleVerticalBorderAdded, Boolean singleHorizontalBorderAdded)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer, Boolean disposeEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the (free) [RightHand DataSet Visualizer](http://blog.rthand.com/post/2009/06/23/Packing-assemblies-to-a-single-file-for-RighthandDatasetVisualizer.aspx) now. Doesn't have this issue and is a lot more powerful.

Comment: I have started using RightHand DataSet Visualizer after reading this answer and I have found this tool much more useful than the default visualizer. Many thanks for the advice!